# C# -Implicit constructor from dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic, constructor, implicit-conversion

Given the following `class`:

```
public class DataPair{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public DataPair(string key, object value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Is there any chance to implement something like

```
public static implicit operator DataPair(dynamic value)
{
    return new DataPair(value.Key, value.Value);
}
```

So I can create a new instance this way

```
DataPair myInstance = {"key", "value"};
```

Comment: Why don't you use Object Initialization that call deafult construtor if exist?

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki: Could you clarify how exactly I would call the object initialization?

Comment: I think this example from documentations will clarify it simply  :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki: Ok. As a lazy developer I thought there would be some "shorthand" way in order to always write `new DataPair{Key = "key", Value = "value"}`. E.g. a method `void Create(params DataPair[] values)` to be called like `Create({"key1", "value1"},{"key2", "value2"})`

Comment: I, also lazy developer, think `new DataPair{Key = "key", Value = "value"}` is very short. If you want shorter you can create constructior with 2 parameters. Object initialisator also let you assign obejcts to `List<>` in the way `{{Key = "key", Value = "value"}{Key = "key", Value = "value"}{Key = "key", Value = "value"}}`.

Comment: And remember that Object Inintialisator always (if exist) calls default construtor before assigning variables...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the closest you're going to get:

```
public static implicit operator DataPair(string[] values)
{
    return new DataPair(values[0], values[1]);
}
```

And use it like:

```
DataPair myInstance = new []{"gr", "value"};
```

That's the closest you're going to get, as the `= {"gr", "value"};` syntax is reserved for arrays, which you cannot subclass.

Answer (score 8):

Finally, with C# 7, you may use ValueTuples like

```
public static implicit operator DataPair((string key, object value) value)
{
    return new DataPair(value.key, value.value);
}
```

and use it like

```
DataPair dp = ("key", 234);
```